# How to simplify logic/methods to enhance ATM java project

Tags: java, switch-statement, logical-operators

This is not a new question nor is it a question to be answered to turn in as an assignment as this has already been turned in about a year ago.  I started getting into Java last summer and had an assignment that required us to write a simple ATM application.  Below is my code with the results, but as I'm looking at the code a year later, I see where it could have been improved.  I'm looking at the do while loop in the main program and the Switch statements below that.  I'm thinking that the print statements can be removed and placed within its respective method and simply call on those methods.  That part I feel is more self explanatory as opposed to the do while above where I feel that the logic can be simplified such as the first or even second if statement and place it outside of the loop.  However, I keep getting an exception error when I try it.  Anyway, below is my original project.  Any input, suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

```
import java.util.*;

public class ATM {

    public static Scanner kbd = new Scanner(System.in);
    // The checkID method determines if acctNum is a valid account number
    // and pwd is the correct password for the account.  If the account information
    // is valid, the method returns the current account balance, as a string.
    // If the account information is invalid, the method returns the string "error".
    public static String checkID(String acctNum, String pwd)
    {
        String result = "error";

        // Strings a, b, and c contain the valid account numbers and passwords.
        // For each string, the account number is listed first, followed by
        // a space, followed by the password for the account, followed by a space,
        // followed by the current balance.
        String a = "44567-5 mypassword 520.36";
        String b = "1234567-6 anotherpassword 48.20";
        String c = "4321-0 betterpassword 96.74";

        if (acctNum.equals(a.substring(0, a.indexOf(" "))) && 
                pwd.equals(a.substring(a.indexOf(" ")+1,a.lastIndexOf(" "))))
            return result = a.substring(a.lastIndexOf(" ") + 1);

        if (acctNum.equals(b.substring(0, b.indexOf(" "))) && 
                pwd.equals(b.substring(b.indexOf(" ")+1,b.lastIndexOf(" "))))
            return result = b.substring(b.lastIndexOf(" ") + 1);

        if (acctNum.equals(c.substring(0, c.indexOf(" "))) && 
                pwd.equals(c.substring(c.indexOf(" ") + 1,c.lastIndexOf(" "))))
            return result = c.substring(c.lastIndexOf(" ") + 1);

        return result;
    }

    public static int menu()
    {
        int menuChoice;
        do
        { 
            System.out.print("\nPlease Choose From the Following Options:"
                    + "\n 1. Display Balance \n 2. Deposit"
                    + "\n 3. Withdraw\n 4. Log Out\n\n");

            menuChoice = kbd.nextInt();

            if (menuChoice < 1 || menuChoice > 4){
                System.out.println("error");
            }

        }while (menuChoice < 1 || menuChoice > 4);

        return menuChoice;
    }

    public static void displayBalance(double x)
    {
        System.out.printf("\nYour Current Balance is $%.2f\n", x);
    }

    public static double deposit(double x, double y)
    {
        double depositAmt = y, currentBal = x;
        double newBalance = depositAmt + currentBal;

        System.out.printf("Your New Balance is $%.2f\n",  newBalance);

        return newBalance;
    }

    public static double withdraw(double x, double y)
    {
        double withdrawAmt = y, currentBal = x, newBalance;

        newBalance = currentBal - withdrawAmt;
        System.out.printf("Your New Balance is %.2f\n",newBalance);

        return newBalance;  
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String accNum, pass, origBal = "error";
        int count = 0, menuOption = 0;
        double depositAmt = 0, withdrawAmt = 0, currentBal=0; 
        boolean  foundNonDigit;
        //loop that will count the number of login attempts
        //you make and will exit program if it is more than 3.
        //as long as oriBal equals an error.  
        do{
            foundNonDigit = false;
            System.out.println("Please Enter Your Account Number: ");
            accNum = kbd.next();

            System.out.println("Enter Your Password: ");
            pass = kbd.next();

            origBal = checkID(accNum, pass);

            count++;

            if (count >= 3 && origBal.equals("error")){
                System.out.print("Maximum Login Attempts Reached.");
                System.exit(0);
            }
            if (!(origBal.equals("error"))){
                System.out.println("\nYour New Balance is: $ "+ origBal);
            }
            else
                System.out.println(origBal);


        }while(origBal.equals("error"));

        currentBal=Double.parseDouble(origBal);
        //this loop will keep track of the options that 
        //the user inputs in for the menu. and will 
        //give the option of deposit, withdraw, or logout.

        while (menuOption != 4)
        { 
            menuOption=menu();
            switch (menuOption)
            {
            case 1:
                displayBalance(currentBal);
                break;
            case 2:
                System.out.print("\nEnter Amount You Wish to Deposit: $ ");
                depositAmt = kbd.nextDouble();
                currentBal=deposit(depositAmt, currentBal);
                break;
            case 3:
                System.out.print("\nEnter Amount You Wish to Withdrawl: $ ");
                withdrawAmt = kbd.nextDouble();

                while(withdrawAmt>currentBal){
                    System.out.print("ERROR: INSUFFICIENT FUNDS!! "
                            + "PLEASE ENTER A DIFFERENT AMOUNT: $");
                    withdrawAmt = kbd.nextDouble();
                }

                currentBal = withdraw(currentBal, withdrawAmt);
                break;
            case 4:
                System.out.print("\nThank For Using My ATM.  Have a Nice Day.  Good-Bye!");
                System.exit(0);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If this program works but needs improvement, I would recommend posting to CodeReview.

Comment: Thanks. I'm updating what I got now, but will definitely post it.  Thanks.